# Virtualbox, containers and the optimal solution environment for data science

Tags: windows, linux, images, file-management, virtual-machine

I am trying to figure out the best combination for the following day to day activities.

I am a fresh graduate and I just started playing around with programming and learning about different virtual environments. I do realize that in my day to day tasks I need different combinations of python versions, Java versions, and other software versions. Moreover, I am installing pip from unknown sources and trying different files from the wild all of which will contain viruses and cause dependency issues etc. Thus, I am trying to plan out the best recovery plan but I am not sure if the following is the sanest way to do it. I am looking for inputs from the users on how they carry their day to day tasks in programming, gaming and banking safely?

Currently, my idea is to run windows 10 normally which will have the Oracle virtual machine running with three instances

1) Linux - for programming in the Anaconda environment

2) Windows 10 - Email and banking etc

3) Windows 10 - Gaming, web surfing and all other miscellaneous stuff

If, I would destroy a dependency or get a virus on any of the instances , I can simply get rid of the whole instance running on the virtual environment and re-install it again.

Any other ways to have a smarter architecture with much lower overhead or even make the above more efficient?

Here is a visualization to make it faster to imagine

[image]

Comment: "get a virus on the Linux instance" - I might worry more about those 2 @ Windows ;-)

Comment: @Mawg haha ! I agree :P I should edit that to "if I mess up something due to pip install...." but ya, what do you recommend ?

Comment: To be honest, your question is off-topic here (but I would love to hear an answer). I think multiple VMs are the way to go. I would be careful about the shared directory, definitely data only, no apps, if you are convened about security. Perhaps gaming on the host, as a VM will add some latency?  Anyone know where this might be on-topic?

Comment: If a moderator can move this to the write topic it would be great !

Comment: @Mawg My guess would be SuperUser, but I'm not 100% certain about whether they would accept it because it's largely opinion based.

Comment: It ***does*** sound opinion based, but perhaps if it asked for an optimal solution? Or some other wording implying something (mathematically) justifiable, rather than just "I think...

Comment: @Mawg can you kindly migrate this question to SU ? :)

Comment: I don't have that power, but @Izzy might ... What do you think, Izzy, would this question acceptable there, or is it "primarily opinion based"?